# Argument passed to verify() is of type KafkaProducerService and is not a mock

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockito, mockk, mockk-verify

I get an error when running the below test.

```
@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)
class SenderServiceTest {

   @MockK
   lateinit var kafkaService: KafkaService<KeyType, MessageType>


   @Test
   fun `Send message`() {
      val key = KeyType()
      val value = MessageType()
      verify(kafkaService).send(key, value)
   }
}

@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = ["kafka.enabled"])
class KafkaService<K, V>(val producerFactory: ProducerFactory<K, V>, val names: KafkaNames) {

   fun send(key: K, value: V) {
     // some code to send the message.
   }

}
```

The error is

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type KafkaService and is not a mock!
Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!
```

I am not sure why it says the mock bean is not a mock. Someone can help to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 2 mocking frameworks in one test.
You need to use verify belonging to framework you used to construct the mock.

Check [verify in MockK guidebook](https://notwoods.github.io/mockk-guidebook/docs/mockito-migrate/verify/#verify):

Mockito

```
// Mockito
val mockedFile = mock(File::class.java)

mockedFile.read()
verify(mockedFile).read()
```

MockK:

```
// MockK
val mockedFile = mockk<File>()

mockedFile.read()
verify { mockedFile.read() }
```